# strange behavior with showing images using OpenCV and Qt

Tags: c++, c, qt, sockets, opencv

I'm capturing images from a Cam using OpenCV C API and send them using TCP sockets.

The server is running C++ (QT) and receive the frame.

The process is working fine and I can see the images on the server.

The weird problem is when I close both programs and rerun the client and the server, I can see the previous frame again that I saw in the previous test.

If, I close both programs again and rerun them, I can see a new frame not the second one, and the process continues.

**To make it more clear:**

> capture1, close, cap1, close, cap3, close, cap3, close, cap5 ......etc

I didn't see something like this before!

Comment: Are you using any temporary storage, like a file that is lasting longer than it should?

Comment: No temp. storage, from the cam directly.

Comment: How do you capture/release the frame? How do you send/receive frames? (These are 2 places where buffering may happen). Can you paste relevant code snippets?

Comment: Ok, I am trying to make a simple code to proof the concept.( my code is huge).

Comment: Have you tried launching the server on another machine? This way we can exclude the cam driver and other platform specifics.

Comment: Without source code we will be guessing forever. Just don't forget to **release** the capture interface at the end of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem before.

the frame size is pretty much and you read from the buffer in a random way (just guessing) , you have to make a timer or an acknowledge between the camera and OpenCV.

Just try to control the way the camera is capturing frames.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know about TCP/IP programming or client/server much...but all I can suggest is initialize the images, generally in the constructors of the camera/client/server class ,

```
    Mat Frame = Mat::zeros(rows,cols,CV_8UC3);
```

so that every time the client/server is initialized or before you are ready to exchange images...the start up image is a blank image...

you must be initializing using `cvCreatImage()`..so you can do the following...

```
IplImage *m = cvCreateImage(cvSize(200,200),8,3);// say its 200 x 200
cvZero(m);
cvShowImage("BLANK",m);
cvvWaitKey();
```

this shows a black image with each pixel as zero...

Comment: actually I am constructing the image on the server, each time a new IplImage is initialized.

Comment: No it gives me an exception: unknown array type.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this issue comes from the camera. It seems that camera has to receive any acknowledgment once a frame is grabbed. One thing you can try is go to the line of code that sends the image and save the image in the disk in order to check if cap1 is sent twice.